# How to pass my ints from my Array as separate Ints in a Method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am currently working on a project where I created an Array with Ints to cover a playing field.
My problem is that I need to pass each value of the Array as a separate int to a method.

Example below:

```
int [] myArray = new int [9];
```

To the method:

```
public static void createFields(int f3, int f4, int f5, int f6, int f7, int f8, int f9, int f10, int f11)
```

I know that it might be easier to change the method call and just give it the array and work with the `Array` instead of each variable, but I would like to know if there is a smooth way to solve it with each variable called?

Comment: If you only want one item at a time you can use a loop.

Comment: Out of curiosity: is there a reason why the method signature of `createFields` looks like that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple solution via arrays, you have to do array[0], array[1] array[2] etc.

However if you use lists you can neatly use list.remove(0), list.remove(0), list.remove(0) which looks great but 1. changes the list 2. not so cpu efficient.

You can also look into vararg methods which do that the other way around - you can pass in separate ints and treat them as an int[].

Via reflection you should be able to use the int[] as the vararg parameter of the Method.invoke() which would automatically separate them.

Comment: Thanks! I know there are better ways to write it. Just wanted to know if there is maybe a smooth answer I am not seeing without changing the general method call.

Comment: This just changes the array notation to another place. It doesnt remove it.

Comment: Sorry which solution are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

why not you are not using

```
createFields(myArray[0], myArray[1], myArray[2], myArray[3], myArray[4],myArray[5],myArray[6], myArray[7], myArray[8]);
```

i cant see any other way if you have to create method like that;

Comment: Thanks! I know there are better ways to write it. Just wanted to know if there is maybe a smooth answer I am not seeing without changing the general method call.